# Where are the Steam-Link statistic snapshots located?

Tags: steam, steam-in-home-streaming, steam-link

In Steam, when you go to *Settings* -> *In-Home Streaming* -> *Advanced client options*, you can find the option to display performance information at the client side during streaming
[image: Screenshot of menus showing how to turn on performance information display]
If you check it, streaming performance information is displayed at the screen and it's written:

> Press F8 or START + X to save snapshot on remote computer

Where are these snapshots stored on the remote computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/homestream/discussions/0/540732888908569487/) on Steam Community forums, it is stored in `C:\Path\to\SteamDirectory\streaming\Name_of_the_game.zip`(assuming C is the hard drive where Steam is installed):

> Host computer, Steam directory in a folder named streaming, it
>   creates a zip file with the name of the game you pressed f8 in

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Linux host, while streaming the desktop or big picture mode, the directory is:

```
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/streaming
```

Only the F8 method worked, Win+X did not.